# Arduino relay module working in a wrong way

Tags: relay

I have an Arduino Mega and a 4-channel relay module.

This is the [relay](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0057OC5O8) module.

When the Arduino digital output is LOW, the relay is energized.  When the Arduino output is HIGH, the relay coil is de-energized.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hiii brother, yes all relays has this problem exept keystudio relay modules, you can fix it about using a trasintor npn 2a2222 and connect gnd to collector, pin x to base and relay pin to emetor,

Answer (score 2):

That's how they're designed to work energized is LOW de-energized is HIGH you just need to take this into account when writing your Arduino code

Comment: Indeed, while not particularly relevant with an ATmega, historically low-side outputs have been stronger than high-side ones, so when driving an LED (in this case probably one inside an optocoupler on the relay board) it has been conventional to use the I/O pin to drive the LED cathode, while wiring the Anode to the supply.  (It doesn't really matter which side the current limit resistor goes on, since the same current flows in the entirety of the path).

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation or watch/read any tutorials on the mechanical relay you are using you will learn that LOW is active and HIGH is inactive for these devices. There is no way to change that behavior, that is how they are built. (Well, you can, but it's not worth the effort)

This design is intentional to prevent relay activation on power-up or system reset. And be sure to put this code in your setup routine to ensure proper system initialization.

```
digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);
pinMode(Relay, OUTPUT);
```

Where Relay is the pin variable you defined for your relay.

Just code your routine using LOW to activate the relay when necessary.

Try this tutorial [4 channel relay tutorial](http://arduinobasics.blogspot.com/2014/09/relay-module.html)

Comment: I would first set it to output, and then set it high? Not sure if it makes a difference though.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. some boards are working in wrong way. I suggest you to build the relay board your self. [image: relay board]. Its better to plan your project according to your requirement.

Comment: The board is not "working in wrong way". It was designed to operate this way, and the user "Bra1n" gives the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can purchase relay boards that are active high or active low or selectable, your choice. You need to read the description to determine what type it is. Here is a link for one that is selectable high or low active: "https://www.rajguruelectronics.com/Product/1730/1%20channel%20relay%20board%20with%20high%20low%20level%20trigger.pdf" This is an example not a recommendation. These are very popular with the Arduino crowd.